# Android remote view pending Intent not working

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent, remoteview

I have a service that I need to stop using a pending intent from the remoteview that is showing a custom notification. I have set the pending intent and registered the broadcast receiver in the manifest. However when I am clicking the button nothing happens. The broadcast receiver is an inner class of the service class.

The inner class broadcast receiver:

```
public class CancelDownload extends BroadcastReceiver{

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onReceive: cancel intent");
            if(Objects.equals(intent.getAction(), VIDEODOWNLOADACTIONS.STOP)){
                stopSelf();
                CustomModel model = CustomModel.getInstance();
                if (model != null) {

                    model.changeState();
                }
                notificationManager.cancel(notificationId);
                database.setDownloadFileAsFailed(fileID);
                File emptyfile = new File(destinationPath);
                if (emptyfile.exists()) {
                    emptyfile.delete();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Manifest:

```
 <receiver android:name=".data.VideoDownloadService$CancelDownload"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="my.action.stopdownload"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Notification code:

```
   RemoteViews downloadViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.notificaition_layout);
            Intent cancelIntent = new Intent(context, VideoDownloadService.CancelDownload.class);
            cancelIntent.setAction(VIDEODOWNLOADACTIONS.STOP);
            PendingIntent cancelPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, cancelIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

//trying both here

```
downloadViews.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.cancel,cancelPendingIntent);
            downloadViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.cancel,cancelPendingIntent);
```

//setting the view to the notification

```
 builder.setContent(downloadViews)
         .setCustomBigContentView(downloadViews);
```

When I click the button nothing happens the button id is correct. The broadcast receiver has to be an inner class because I have plenty of operations that I want to do if the user clicks cancel. 
How do I make it work. Please help.

Comment: *The broadcast receiver is an inner class of the service class.* (and non static)  **obviously that's the first problem** *`PendingIntent.getActivity`* for `BroadcastReceiver` ? that's second problem

Comment: I used getBroadcast sorry

Comment: Y cannot it be an innerclass I have to use plenty of variables from the service class that's the problem man

Comment: Obviously you cannot do this ... `BroadcastReceiver` cannot be non static inner class

Comment: so i make the broadcast receiver into another class??

Comment: any way to avoid that??

Comment: Use some event bus to communication between real BroadcastReceiver and Service

Comment: whats that supposed to mean??